# error 404 showing for each controller after user authorization via ldap

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, ldap

#### Scenario:

I'm implementing `asp.net core 3.1 MVC` project. I authorize my user via `ldap` Active Directory service. The user authenticates successfully and enter into my website. but after clicking on each menu item in order to see the related controller index it shows white page. I wrote on top of all my controller class [Authorize] keyword in order to let any authorized user to see all controllers.

#### My Problem is:

when user clicks on each menu item in home in order to see the related controller's index, it shows white page and when I publish my project on ldap server, it shows me 404 error. I appreciate if any one can suggest me a solution. It seems to the routing has problem but I'm not sure. I even wrote on top of my controller class the keyword [AllowAnonymous] but still I see white pages for index pages for each controller. Should I add anything to startup.cs for AutheticationHelper or CustomAuthenticationMiddleware as a service?

Here is my sign in method in account controller

```
namespace CSDDashboard.Controllers
{
    [Route("[controller]/[action]")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        private readonly LdapUserManager _userManager;
        private readonly LdapSignInManager _signInManager;
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public AccountController(
            LdapUserManager userManager,
            LdapSignInManager signInManager,
            ILogger<AccountController> logger)
        {
            this._userManager = userManager;
            this._signInManager = signInManager;
            this._logger = logger;
        }
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Signin(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            // Clear the existing external cookie to ensure a clean login process
            await this.HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);

            this.ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;

            return this.View();
        }
    [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Signin(SigninViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
        {
            this.ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;

            using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "tehran.iri"))
            {
                // validate the user's credentials
                //var result = ctx.ValidateCredentials(model.UserName, model.Password);
                //    try { 
                if (ctx.ValidateCredentials(model.UserName, model.Password))
                {
                    // credentials are OK --> allow user in
                    HttpContext.Session.MarkAsAuthenticated(model.UserName);
                    
                    //Added recently
                    Debug.Writeline(string.Format("Redirection to {0}", returnUrl);
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                     
                }
                else
                {
                    this.TempData["ErrorMessage"] = "The username and/or password are incorrect!";

                    return this.View(model);
                    // credentials aren't OK --> send back error message
                }
}

}}}
```

Here is my middleware class and AuthenticationHelper class

```
     public static class AuthenticationHelper
        {
            private const string SessionKey = "AuthenticationHelper.UserName";
    
            public static void MarkAsAuthenticated(this Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.ISession session, string authenticatedUserName)
            {
                session.SetString(SessionKey, authenticatedUserName);
            }
    
            public static ClaimsPrincipal GetAuthenticatedUser(this Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.ISession session)
            {
                string authenticatedUserName = session.GetString(SessionKey);
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(authenticatedUserName)) return null;
                return new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(authenticatedUserName), Array.Empty<string>());
            }
        }

 public class CustomAuthenticationMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public CustomAuthenticationMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            ClaimsPrincipal user = context.Session.GetAuthenticatedUser();
            if (user != null) context.User = user;
            await _next(context);
        }
    }

public static class CustomAuthenticationMiddlewareExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseCustomAuthentication(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<CustomAuthenticationMiddleware>();
    }
}
```

Here is my code in statrup.cs:

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {



   services.Configure<LdapSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("LdapSettings"));
        services.AddDbContext<LdapDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlite(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("CSDDashboardContext")));

        //-------------------------------------------------
        services.AddIdentity<LdapUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<LdapDbContext>()
            .AddUserManager<LdapUserManager>()
            .AddSignInManager<LdapSignInManager>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
                        {
                            options.Cookie.Name = "CSDDashboard";
                            options.LoginPath = "/Account/Signin"; // If the LoginPath is not set here, ASP.NET Core will default to /Account/Login
                            options.LogoutPath = "/Account/Signout"; // If the LogoutPath is not set here, ASP.NET Core will default to /Account/Logout
                            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied"; // If the AccessDeniedPath is not set here, ASP.NET Core will default to /Account/AccessDenied
                            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
                            options.ReturnUrlParameter = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.ReturnUrlParameter;
                        });
        services.AddRazorPages();
        
        services.AddTransient<ILdapService, LdapService>();

        //-------------------------------------------------

        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);//We set Time here 
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        });
        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
        

        //Notice this is NOT the same class... Assuming this is a valid DBContext.  You need to add this class as well.
        services.AddDbContext<CSSDDashboardContext>(options =>
                     options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("CSDDashboardContext")));

        services.AddDbContext<CSDDashboardContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("CSDDashboardContext")));

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        
        //  app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage(options);
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
       
        
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
           app.UseSession();
      
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseCustomAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
      
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
//Here are all of my controllers, but as it seems just I can uncomment one controller pattern here, I commented all the others
        //     pattern: "{controller=Applications}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        //pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        //        pattern: "{controller=ApiApplications}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                pattern: "{controller=Gates}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

Comment: You should add some of your relevant codes and error

Comment: I added "Debug.Writeline(string.Format("Redirection to {0}", returnUrl);" inside the body of my sign in method and in the debug cosole it printed "Redirection to /". It seems to me the redirection doesn't go to any specific URL after authorization. But I don't have any opinion how can I fix this. I apperciate if anyone helps me regarding to  this? Even I modified my signin method like the following, but there wasn't any change for Redirection result in debug console:     public async Task<IActionResult> Signin(SigninViewModel model, string returnUrl)